# Is there a way I can extract markers on a map image using python?

Tags: python, google-maps, image-processing, maps

I have an image here, [sample map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VtBv.jpg)

I wish to extract red lines on the map. The lines represent the number of times a user has chosen a path. The darker the color, the more times he chose that path.

Also, if I know the zoom level of the map (in this case 11), can I calculate the distance traveled for every color marker?

Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try this code -**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
result = image.copy()
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([155,25,0])
upper = np.array([179,255,255])
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(result, result, mask=mask)

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**Output -**

[image]